# How to connect one window with another?

Tags: xcode

I tried to use method

> -(IBAction)gotoview1
>
> {
>   [view1 setHidden:YES];
>
> [view2 setHidden:NO];
>   }

But it didn't work

Comment: What is your target: Mac OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

add the view whichever you want as subview. like this [self.view addsubview:view1];
After that add secondview .Then if you want to see the first view do this [self.view removefromsuperview]